# Enabling compression with WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, http, http-headers

I am using System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile to download a large number of html files from a public web server. I would like to enable compression because that could cut the data transfers by a large factor. I was told in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11670708/154766) that I should set the "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" header. WebClient has a Headers property that would allow doing that.

I have a few questions about this:

1. Assuming the web server recognizes the header, would this work with
   the DownloadFile method, or only with the DownloadData method? I
   couldn't find any information about this on MSDN or other sites.
2. If it doesn't work with DownloadFile, what would be the simplest way
   of implementing downloading compressed data to a file?
3. Does any other header need to be set for the server to compress its
   data? In an old [codinghorror.com](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/netwebclient-and-gzip.html) entry, Jeff Atwood said the
   "UserAgent" header also needs to be set, but I don't know what the
   value should be.

Comment: Your Answer Is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914874/3263653

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. DownloadFile is just a wrapper around a raw WebRequest; it just processes the result and packages it as a "file" or a byte array.
2. It works; but the data that is sent to the local file is still compressed, you'll have to decompress it manually.
3. You get a default UserAgent.  There isn't any particular UserAgent values necessary, unless the site your accessing requires one.  But, you'll have to find that out. (Jeff's post suggest Google requires one; but I don't know if that still true)